# How to make data available from Athena when underlying S3 partition is updated by spark?

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, high-availability, amazon-athena

I'm writing an Apache-spark job which process streaming data and writes to S3 bucket. There are tables created in AWS Athena using this data for query purpose. This data is also partitioned on a few fields like customerid, datetime etc. Spark job is using S3A committer to write to S3.  Since data is coming at regular intervals, spark job process this data and merges with existing data in S3 bucket (reads the existing partition, merges with newly arrived data and overwrite partition).

My concern is - since these partitions are being updated throughout the day and Writing S3 partition is not an atomic operation, when an partition is updated (over written) and if a client queries data at that very moment, how it is going to behave? How should I handle partition update so that data is always available?

Comment: Msck repair table is performed by job . That is not the problem. When the partition is being overwritten , how would Athena query behave?

Comment: i just tested and my previous statement is wrong. Athena is able to read the updated/overwritten data instantaneously if the partition already existed in the data catalog. you will not see an intermediate result though. only data from either the fully updated/overwritten file or the older version of the file.